# How to set @RolesAllowed dynamically in EJB 3

Tags: java, security, authorization, ejb-3.0

I'm using roles authorization in my application as below,

```
**@RolesAllowed("Admin")**
public class ExampleResource {
//
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  **@RolesAllowed({"Admin", "User"})**
  public Response getUsers(){
   }
}
```

The authorization is working fine when login as "Admin/User". Similarly I applied the roles for many resource class.

**But I want to handle @RolesAllowed to set dynamically instead of defined it as a declarative annotation**. Or Is there any other way to handle the role authorization using EJB3 or Java ee security?

Please give your ideas or example to implement it.

Thanks,

Regards,
Ubai

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Resource` to inject EJBContext (or SessionContext), and call isCallerInRole(String roleName) and throw an exception (or whatever) if it returns false.  This is basically what `@RolesAllowed` does under the covers.

Comment: Hi @bKail, Thanks for your reply. Yes As Per your reply, I tried to check the roles isCallerInRole(String roleName) using SessionContext. But I got an exception as `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No mapping available for role reference Admin`. Could you please reply what the cause of this?

Comment: I'm not sure. It sounds like a vendor-specific exception. Have you declared the role elsewhere, perhaps via `@DeclareRoles`? Perhaps update your description with a full stack trace?